# How to name a new method and have it pass through a function?

Tags: javascript

```
      var getInitials = .charAt(0).toUpperCase() 

      function Person(firstName, lastName) {
      firstName.getInitials + lastName.getInitials
        }
      Person(tom,smith);


       //const johnDoe = new Person('john', 'doe');
       //console.log(johnDoe.getInitials(), '<-- should be "JD"');
```

Add a method to the Person's prototype called "getInitials" that returns the first letter of their first and last name, both capitalized. Not sure what I'm doing wrong here? Syntax error?

Comment: Please, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: `var getInitials = .charAt(0).toUpperCase()` is not valid JavaScript. You are also not defining a method on the prototype. `firstName.getInitials + lastName.getInitials` also seems kind of arbitrary. If you want to learn about creating classes in JavaScript, read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects

Answer (score 1):

```js
// define a person constructor
function Person(firstName, lastName) {
  this.firstName = firstName;
  this.lastName = lastName;
}
   
// create a method on its prototype
Person.prototype.getInitials = function() {
  //  Rudimentary way of doing it. Add checks
  return this.firstName[0].toUpperCase() + this.lastName[0].toUpperCase()
};

const johnDoe = new Person('tom', 'smith');
console.log(johnDoe.getInitials());
```

Comment: I think the best way to help the OP is to address her/him to learn Object-oriented programming because it seems the OP doesn't have any idea about that paradigm.

Comment: @Ele That is a fair statement

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple problems in your code.

First of all, var getInitials = .charAt(0).toUpperCase() is not a valid JS. If you want to add a method to the String you should added to its prototype:

```
String.prototype.yourCustomStringFunction = function() {
    //insert your code here
}
```

Secondly, your Person function should return a value:

```
function Person(firstName, lastName) {
    return firstName.getInitials() + lastName.getInitials();
}
```

Lastly, strings are defined using quotes(""). So when you fic all of those issues your final code is:

```js
String.prototype.getInitials = function(str) {
  return this.charAt(0).toUpperCase();
}


function Person(firstName, lastName) {
  return firstName.getInitials() + lastName.getInitials();   
}

console.log(Person("John", "Doe"));
```